# Need to make a function which returns an int based on which char argument has more uppercase letters

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

I'm trying to write a function which will:

return  :

```
 0 if the strings have the same number of uppercase letters (A through Z)

-1 if s1 has more uppercase letters than s2

 1 if s2 has more uppercase letters than s1
```

My biggest issue is the fact that strings aren't treated the same way in c as other languages which I have more experience in (java, python) I'm also a bit confused on when I should reference pointers/ dereference them. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int more_caps(char * s1, char * s2);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

int result = more_caps(argv[1], argv[2]);
printf("%d %s %s", result, argv[1], argv[2]);
return 0;
}
//EVERYTHING BEFORE THIS MUST NOT BE CHANGED------


int more_caps(char * s1, char *s2){
char * s1caps = strdup(s1);
char * s2caps = strdup(s2);

int *s1counter;
int *s2counter;

int i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(s1caps); i++){

    int val1;
    val1 = (int) *s1caps[i];

    if (val1 > 65 && val1 <= 90){
        *s1counter += 1;

    } 
}
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(s2caps); i ++ ){

    int val2;
    val2 = (int) *s2caps[i];
    if (val2 > 65 && val2 <= 90){
        *s2counter += 1;
    }
}

if (*s1counter > *s2counter){
    printf("\n");
    return -1;
}
if (*s1counter < *s2counter){
    printf("\n");
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

I'm really confused on parsing through a char object and how i need to allocate memory or something. From reading the documentation, strdup(char) allocates the exact memory + 1 byte for the character i'm putting in the function?   In anycase it's either seg faults or "indirection requires pointer operand". Any help? Thanks

Comment: You don't need `strdup` and you don't need any memory allocation. You can treat `s1` and `s2` as arrays, e.g. `for (i=0;s1[i]!='\0';i++) printf("%c\n",s1[i]);`

Comment: Change all the *s1counter to just s1counter.  The same for s2counter. You don't need a pointer here, and if you tried to run this code it would core dump because those pointers don't point anywhere.  Remember to initialize your counters to 0 as C doesn't guarantee any particular value you don't set yourself. As user3386109 said, you don't need strdup, but if you did need it, remember to free the strings when finished else you will be leaking memory.

Comment: Thank you guys. Why allocate memory for chars if you can parse through it regularly anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to duplicate the strings nor use of magic numbers like `65`.  March down each string counting the occurrences of upper case letters using `isupper()`

```
#include <ctype.h>

int more_caps(char * s1, char *s2) {
  unsigned up_count1 = 0;
  // while pointer is not point to the terminating null character ...
  while (*s1) {
    if (isupper(*s1)) up_count1++;
    s1++;
  }

  unsigned up_count2 = 0;
  while (*s2) {
    if (isupper(*s2)) up_count2++;
    s2++;
  }

  // The compare/subtraction is idiomatic in C
  // Each compare returns 0 or 1
  return (up_count2 > up_count1) - (up_count2 < up_count1);
}
```

Some pedantic improvements for your later C education:

- When using an index in C, or a count of elements in an array, the type `size_t` is preferred as it is the right size to index any array.  Type `int` is sometimes too narrow.

  ```
   size_t up_count1 = 0;
  ```
- The `is...()` functions take `int` values in the range `unsigned char` and `EOF`.  Casting to `unsigned char` is warranted here, but I doubt your test cases will expose the weakness of a non-casted usage.

  ```
  if (isupper((unsigned char) *s1)) up_count1++;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int more_caps(char * s1, char * s2);

int main(int argc, char **argv){

int result = more_caps(argv[1], argv[2]);
printf("%d %s %s", result, argv[1], argv[2]);
return 0;
}

int more_caps(char * s1, char *s2){
//char * s1caps = strdup(s1);
//char * s2caps = strdup(s2);

int s1counter;
int s2counter;

s1counter = 0;
s2counter = 0;
int i;
for(i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++){

    int val1;
    val1 = (int ) s1[i];

    if (val1 > 65 && val1 <= 90){
        s1counter += 1;

    } 
}
for (i = 0; s2[i] != '\0'; i ++ ){

    int val2;
    val2 = (int ) s2[i];
    if (val2 > 65 && val2 <= 90){
        s2counter += 1;
    }
}

if (s1counter > s2counter){
    printf("\n");
    return -1;
}
if (s1counter < s2counter){
    printf("\n");
    return 1;
}
else {
    return 0;
}
}
```

The fixed function which seems to work quite well. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your check for uppercase is cruel and unusual. C provides the `isupper()` function.

Comment: That's much better. I was going to suggest `if (val1>= 'A' && val1<= 'Z')` since using character constants improves readability, but the suggestion by @EOF is even better.